# (HTML/CSS) I want to use my css with all my hyperlink

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS

```
img{width:85%; height:auto;}
#thumbwrap {
    position:relative;
}
.thumb img { 
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:3px;
    float:left;
}
.thumb span { 
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.thumb:hover, .thumb:hover span { 
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:1;
}
```

my html

```
<a class="thumb" href="T1" target="_blank">T1<span><img src="xxx" alt=""></span><br></a>

<a href="T2" target="_blank">T2<span><img src="xxx" alt=""></span><br></a>
```

Is there any way I can use my class="thumb" with all `<a></a>` without type it like first one.

Comment: You'll either need to give all your links the thumb class or change your CSS rules so that `.thumb` is `a`

Comment: Putting a class on an element is one of the actual benefits of CSS here - sort of like saying "I want to have a fleet of taxis but don't want hinges on the doors" possible but not as nice to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `thumb` class, use the html tag `a` since you want all `a tags` to get the same css styling. Try the following snippet.

```css
img{width:85%; height:auto;}
#thumbwrap {
    position:relative;
}
a img { 
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:3px;
    float:left;
}
a span { 
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
a:hover, a:hover span { 
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<a href="T1" target="_blank">T1<span><img src="xxx" alt=""></span><br></a>

<a href="T2" target="_blank">T2<span><img src="xxx" alt=""></span><br></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just forget `.thumb` then and replace it with `a` everywhere:

```
img {
   width:85%; height:auto;
}
#thumbwrap {
    position:relative;
}
a img { 
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:3px;
    float:left;
}
a span { 
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
}
a:hover, a:hover span { 
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add thumb class to all the a tags by using simple jquery script line

```
$('a').addClass('thumb');
```